# CSS :not() selector. Apply style if parent does not exist

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to apply a style to a div based on its parent class. I am using the :not() selector to select the div whose parent is not `.container1`, the second div should be red, but it's not working.

**Example 1**

```css
.myDiv:not(.container1) > .myDiv {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="myDiv">Div 1</div>
</div>

<div class="container2">
  <div class="myDiv">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

**Example 2**

```css
.myDiv:not(.container1 .myDiv) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="myDiv">Div 1</div>
</div>

<div class="container2">
  <div class="myDiv">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

Is this even possible with CSS? Or is my syntax just off?

Comment: The first example is way off - `.myDiv:not(.container1)` represents an element that contains one of the classes but not the other. You are essentially trying to match a `.myDiv` that is a child of another `.myDiv`. The second example happens to be a new addition to selectors-4 and is thus not very well supported at the moment, but once it is, it will do exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're selecting wrong elements. No reverse lookups possible, see here:

```css
div:not(.container1) > .myDiv {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="myDiv">Div 1</div>
</div>

<div class="container2">
  <div class="myDiv">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

---

Ideally, you'd group those parent divs under the same class in order to avoid the super-generic `div` selector:

```css
.container:not(.container1) > .myDiv {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container container1">
  <div class="myDiv">Div 1</div>
</div>

<div class="container container2">
  <div class="myDiv">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

CSS can't do "parent lookups" like that. You would need to reverse the structure to something like:

```
.my-container:not(.container1) .myDiv
```

Granted, you would need to add the shared `my-container` class to all "parent" divs of interest.